# intellij hybris class recompile not working

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I installed hybris plugin.
Imported project with it.
Have done `ant clean all`.
Then, if I try to `build->recompile class` it's not working. Seems like idea doesn't see classes generated by ant.
If I do `build->rebuild project` and then `build->recompile` class it's working fine, but it's not convenient at all. I believe there is fix to this, but I couldn't find it.
This is usual error I've got(packages are different for different cases):
[image]

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?'ant clean all' command is enough to create a build from scratch.

Comment: When I'm trying to hotswap class, this happens, because I haven't build project with Idea before the start up. Ant clean all won't help in this case. Project will start and work fine, but hotswap (with build->recompile) won't work.

Comment: @Evgenii, hi, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

> this is essentially the expected behaviour. You can't mix "ant" build
>   and "native IDEA" build. Those are two separate build systems.

This is an explanation of hybris plugin developer ([hybris-integration.atlassian.net/browse/IIPS-120](https://hybris-integration.atlassian.net/browse/IIPS-120?focusedCommentId=18392&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-18392))

And he suggests a solution for that:

- before you try to import the project you need to do ant clean all (you will not need to use ant afterwards)
- import the project using hybris plugin.
- Press Build->Recompile project

Then you can create or modify your test run configuration if needed.
Recompile your classes and so on directly in Idea.

Also, he mentioned deal with JRebel here ([hybris-integration.atlassian.net/browse/IIPS-47](https://hybris-integration.atlassian.net/browse/IIPS-47?focusedCommentId=17501&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17501))

> we support both compilation modes. Ant targets and idea internal. They
>   shouldn't be mixed as idea has it's own compilation model/cache. If
>   you use idea compilation then you can use JRebel or hotswap.

Answer (score 0):

You cant hotswap classes in hybris without the help of a hotswap agent.There is a tool available in the market called [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). It is a good commercial tool if one can afford. However, if you are an open-sourcist, there is a promising alternative to JRebel, which is [DCEVM](http://hotswapagent.org/mydoc_quickstart.html) (Dynamic Code Evolution Virtual Machine) along with HotswapAgent.

Comment: Well, I can with idea if I build project with ide before start, just by recompiling class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this help, 
you can start **another** cmd console, and run
`setantenv` and `ant build`  to hotswap class in runtime.